# Simple debugging query

Tags: php, debugging

I have a small issue actually getting variable to show - let alone how to figure out why my images are not uploading.
On my form I have the following textarea -

> `<input type="file" name="imageNew" />`

in the page to which this form is posted I have -

> `$imagetoshow = $_REQUEST['imageNew'];
>   echo "the image is " + $imagetoshow;
>   exit();`

I simply cant see why this is displaying a "0"?
What I think I need is for someone to point out the obvious to me - obvious to you, not to me. Then I can get on with figuring out why the file isn't uploading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files work a little differently... You need to access the $_FILES superglobal.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

(From that page as well: *Note: Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.*)

Comment: Yeah it does have the multipart/form-data. The link provided is actually where I started with my upload.php file, but the $_REQUEST is so that I can grab the posted values for later.

Comment: You mean that you want to do something different than obtaining the file? If so, what exactly are you trying to do and it's not working?

Comment: Sorry, I probably haven't explained myself too well... i need this value to construct an sql INSERT statement

Comment: @Andrew you can get the value, but its going to be part of $_FILES, understand?

Comment: At some stage it worked, but I'm trying to adapt the uploads.php file to accomodate a different upload to a different db table and inexplicably this no longer seems to get a value from the previous form.

Comment: @Fosco do you mean $_FILES['imageNew'][name]?

Comment: @Andrew `$_FILES['imageNew']['name']`

Comment: Thanks... That sorted the problem, I'm getting a value now.

Answer (score 2):

To get files, you need to use `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`, and the form needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Check out the following link for more about file uploads in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php